# Flash CC 2014 HTML publish JS error

Tags: javascript, flash, export, createjs, adobe-cc

I'm using Flash CC 2014 to create some js/html based interactives.   One thing I've come across, is sometimes the published files fail to run.  It seems like the export fails to include random clips in the library, so you get errors when it attempts to instantiate them, eg...

```
this.instance_1 = new lib.c_hand("synched",0);
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Has anyone had any similar problems?  Is there any way to debug what's going on inside the export script?  After a quick look, I can find JSFL files relating to the export, by it appears that they're all obfuscated :\

At the moment I'm resorting to rebuild the library file by hand from GIT diffs.  Pain.

Comment: The very latest Flash CC now reports line numbers in its debug output, which might give you a better idea of what is going on.

Comment: The problem is, there are no errors in Flash at all.  It pauses at around 80% of publishing, then completes with the usual warnings about frame numbers.

Comment: This may also be a PC issue (Win7), as the files publish OK on OSX.

Comment: I recommend posting something to the Adobe Forum: https://forums.adobe.com/community/flash/flash_general

Comment: Yeah, i've done that too... https://forums.adobe.com/message/6965033  Sorry, should have mentioned that.